# Ada random numbers are identical

Tags: random, ada

I have following problem with my function which should return a random numer. When I want to generate a couple of numbers by calling that function, they are exactly the same. How can I fix the problem of returning the same number all the time when I call the function? I need that random to keep in function.

Here is the code:

```
with Ada.Numerics.discrete_Random

function generate_random_number ( n: in Positive) return Integer is
       subtype Rand_Range is Integer range 0 .. n;
       package Rand_Int is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Rand_Range);
       use Rand_Int;
       gen : Rand_Int.Generator;
       ret_val: Rand_Range;
   begin
      Rand_Int.Reset(gen);
      ret_val := Random(gen);

      return ret_val;
   end;
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245051/ada-seeding-random. I am not familiar with Ada, but it looks as though you are reseeding with the same number every time, even though a cursory look at your code does not make it apparent how.

Comment: If you are getting the same number returned every time, that tells me you are sending it the same seed every time instead of getting the next in a sequence.

Comment: It is seeded with the same seed all time, because when i call this function two times with a couple of seconds delay it returns another random. There's a line which should reset the generator but looks like it don't work.

Comment: If your purpose is to generate a sequence of two or more random numbers, you don't want to reset the generator every time.  Just once.

Comment: Why are you passing an upper limit into the function?  How many different upper limits do you expect to use for the duration of an execution of your program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random generator `gen` should not be local to the function. Currently you are creating it anew on each `generate_random_number` call, and initialising it, so it's not surprising you always get the same result.

If you make `gen` - for instance - a global variable, initialised once, then each time you use it you'll get a new random number. (Yes, global variables are bad : but see below)

Unfortunately this does not play particularly well with the semantics of `function generate_random_number ( n: in Positive)` which can restrict the range of the random number differently each time. The simplest solution is to make `gen` return any valid integer and use modular arithmetic to return a number in the correct range for each call. This will work but you should be aware that it potentially introduces cryptographic weaknesses, beyond my skills to analyze.

If that is the case you will need a different approach, for example creating a different random generator for each range you need; taking care to seed (reset) them differently otherwise there may again be crypto weaknesses such as correlations between different generators.

Now global variables are poor structure for all the usual reasons in any language. So a much better way is to make it a resource by wrapping it in a package.

```
package RandGen is
   function generate_random_number ( n: in Positive) return Positive;
end RandGen;
```

And that is all the client needs to see. The package is implemented as follows:

```
with Ada.Numerics.discrete_Random;
package body RandGen is

   subtype Rand_Range is Positive;
   package Rand_Int is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Rand_Range);

   gen : Rand_Int.Generator;

   function generate_random_number ( n: in Positive) return Integer is
   begin
      return Rand_Int.Random(gen) mod n;  -- or mod n+1 to include the end value
   end generate_random_number;

-- package initialisation part
begin
   Rand_Int.Reset(gen);
end RandGen;
```

EDIT : Jacob's suggestion of rejecting out-of-range values is better but inefficient if n is much smaller than the generator range. One solution might be to create several generators and let the `generate_random_number` function choose the one which covers 0 .. N with least waste.

Comment: Don't ever use `mod` to restrict the interval of random numbers.  Reject excessive values!  (Except for that, your explanations and suggestion are fine.)

Comment: All solutions are good, thanks. Therefore your solution match in most way in my program.

Answer (score 2):

The `Random` procedure with only one parameter is supposed to initiate the random number generator with a "time-dependent state".  However, if it is called more than once rapidly in succession, it is very likely that the "time" that the program uses will be the same each time, since the program is likely to run faster than the clock resolution.  (Try your test with something like `delay 0.5` in between the two uses of `generate_random_number`; most likely you will get two different results.)

In any event, the intended use of a random number generator is to use `Reset` on it once to set the seed, and then generate a sequence of random numbers starting with the seed.  By doing this, you can also use the same seed every time in order to get a duplicatable sequence of random numbers, for testing; or you can use a time-dependent seed.  However, resetting the random number generator every time you want a random number is not the normal or recommended way of using RNG's.  Therefore, you need to move the `Reset` call out of `generate_random_number`.  Unfortunately, this also means that you have to use the same generator even if the `n` parameter will be different on every call, which means you may be forced to use `Float_Random` instead of `Discrete_Random`.

**P.S.** Looking into it further, I found this in G.2.5: "Two different calls to the time-dependent Reset procedure shall reset the generator to different states, *provided that the calls are separated in time by at least one second and not more than fifty years.*"  [Emphasis mine.]  I'm sure that when you tried it, the calls were less than one second apart.

Comment: When I remove the Reset call, function returns always the same value no matter when I call the function nor when I execute the program. Of course I can generate a couple of numbers in my function then remember it, but I need about 10^10 random numbers in specified ranges in my program. Each time i need random number from different ranges, that's the reason of keeping it in function with one parameter.

Comment: @PaulDew Right, you can't have a generator that gets declared anew each time your procedure is called.  I think you'll have to use `Float_Random` and do your own computation--sorry.

Comment: RE P.S. : Exactly as you said. I experimented a little and when I execute program in 'another second sequence' the randoms are another (but the same).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the upper limit can be determined when you start the program:

Package `Random` (specification):

```
with Generic_Random;
with Upper_Limit_Function;
package Random is new Generic_Random (Upper_Limit => Upper_Limit_Function);
```

Generic package `Generic_Random` (specification):

```
generic
   Upper_Limit : Positive;
package Generic_Random is
   subtype Values is Natural range 0 .. Upper_Limit;
   function Value return Values;
end Generic_Random;
```

Generic package `Generic_Random` (body):

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
package body Generic_Random is
   package Random is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Values);

   Source : Random.Generator;

   function Value return Values is
   begin
      return Random.Random (Source);
   end Value;
begin
   Random.Reset (Source);
end Generic_Random;
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct approach IF you are allowed to rewrite the function specification!